# VS2015 RC delay notification

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Since some time i got some issue with my Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. When i am trying to debug my windows form application it's stack and when i click on visual studio window i see message

> "Delay notification"

and i have to option either

> "Switch To"

or

> "Continue waiting"

. And it's never come back to work again i have to restart my computer to work again for some time again and then again. I am using windows 10. Do you have any clue why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Run Visual Studio's **setup** and click **Repair**. It's a long process, but works. Also, check if you have updated the `Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools` extension to the latest version.